# I have a problem with Amber18 configuration at the make install step

Tags: molecular-dynamics, amber

I have a problem installing Amber.
First, I enter the command:

```
./configure --with-python /usr/bin/python3 --with-netcdf $AMBERHOME/netCDF gnu
```

Than make:

```
make FFLAGS="-fallow-argument-mismatch"
```

And this results in following errors:

```
usr/bin/ld: /home/dre/amber18/lib/libcifparse.a(lex.cifp.o):(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `cifpin'; /home/dre/amber18/lib/libcifparse.a(cifparse.o):(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:173: antechamber] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dre/amber18/AmberTools/src/antechamber'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:29: serial] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dre/amber18/AmberTools/src'
make: *** [Makefile:7: install] Error 2
```

The Ubuntu system was freshly installed yesterday, but all the required drivers are already installed.
Obviously, multiple definition of `cifpin' is the problem.
I guess there are some problems with fortran flags.
Please, help me to fix this mistake!

Best regards,

Andrey

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! However since you haven't signed in for 7 months we are closing this as "abandoned" (we're assuming you found an answer or are no longer interested). If you want the question reopened, just write a comment and we can do it!